# Client validation is not working on adding "onclick" command in the input tag

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, razor

```
function updateDetails() {
                document.getElementById('Update').submit();
        }


  @using (Html.BeginForm("UpdateProfile","UpdateProfile",FormMethod.Post,new {id="Update"}))
    {
<input type="submit" id="btnUpdate" value="Save" name="command" onclick="updateDetails();"/>
}
```

On adding onclick to the input tag, clientvalidation is not functioning. I have added the below two parameters in Application_Start method.

> HtmlHelper.ClientValidationEnabled = true;
>    HtmlHelper.UnobtrusiveJavaScriptEnabled = true;

Please help me to resolve this issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are no input fields to validate from your example.

You need to add the relevant inputs with corresponding validation messages i.e.

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Foo)
@Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.Foo)
```

You need the following script references:

```
  <script src="http://ajax.microsoft.com/ajax/jQuery/jquery-1.4.2.min.js"></script>
  <script src="http://ajax.microsoft.com/ajax/jquery.validate/1.7/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>
  <script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Then change your handler to this:

```
$('#Update').submit();
```

I think you are getting the error due to not having a jQuery reference, as .submit is a jQuery function.

**[.submit()](http://api.jquery.com/submit/)**

Comment: I am trying to submit a form. When I tried to submit a button it is throwing a javascript exception "Object doesn't support property or method 'submit'". How can I submit a button click?

Comment: There are couple of input fields. Only thing is I did not put into the question.

Comment: @user3406037 See my updated answer, .submit is a jquery function. :)

Comment: Client Validations are functioning. Also it's giving a javascript error : " Object doesn't support property or method 'submit'"

Comment: @user3406037 No probs. :)

Answer (score 0):

```
function updateDetails() {
            document.getElementById('btnUpdate').submit();
    }
```

it works